# EXTJS MVVM Architecture

Tags: extjs, mvvm

Hi just want to ask is it possible to have two(2) ViewModels in MVVM. Directory model is like this:

- AppView

  - View
  - ViewModel1
  - ViewModel2
  - ViewController (can access two viewsModels)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have two view models for one view.

Comment: Can you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398112/how-can-i-add-geoext3-to-extjs-6-mvvm-architecture) please?