# How can I add GeoExt3 to Extjs 6 MVVM architecture?

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs-mvc, geoext

I want to develop an [Extjs 6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html) application with `MVVM` architecture. In this application, I want to use [GeoExt 3](https://github.com/geoext/geoext3).

I don't know what to do to add GeoExt 3 library to application?

How can I do it?

Comment: Tell us what you've done so far and what the specific problem is. It's almost impossible to answer "I don't know what to do." type of questions when  they are not specific enough.

Comment: My problem was in understanding `packages` in Extjs-6. I must add GeoExt3 to my project as packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a package with GeoExt3. For packaging in Extjs-6 read [heer](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html).

## How to package GeoExt using sencha command

Install `sencha cmd` from here (tested with the
version 6, only as preview right now).

To generate a package you usually first create a sencha `workspace` by issuing

> sencha -sdk /path/to/ext-n.n.n generate workspace /path/to/workspace

Inside of the workspace clone the `geoext3` repository into the `packages` subfolder:

> $ cd /path/to/workspace/packages
>   $ git clone https://github.com/KaiVolland/geoext3.git GeoExt3
>   $ cd GeoExt3

Then you can issue

> $ sencha package build

Alternatively, if your source isn't living inside of a sencha workspace, you can configure the path to a workspace and then build:

> $ sencha config --prop workspace.config.dir=/path/to/workspace/.sencha/workspace then package build

### Adding GeoExt to a local sencha repository

Initalize the local "GeoExt Contributors" repository:

> $ sencha package repo init -name "GeoExt Contributors" -email "dev@geoext.org"

Add the package to this

> $ sencha package add D:/xampp/htdocs/ExtProjects/GeoExt3/build/GeoExt/GeoExt.pkg

create your app as [heer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/getting_started/getting_started.html).
To use this package in a sencha app just add "GeoExt" to the "requires"-array
in your app.json:

```
/**
 * The list of required packages (with optional versions; default is "latest").
 *
 * For example,
 *
 *      "requires": [
 *          "charts"
 *      ]
 */
"requires": [
    "GeoExt"
],
```

and at the end build app as follow:

> $ sencha app build